# `du` get different results on different machines for the same folder

Tags: disk-usage, size

I have a folder(which contains a lot of sub-folders and files) on a machine,
I used

```
   du -m
```

and it shows the disk usage of all sub-folders and files,
anyway, the overall disk usage is 78M

I used `scp -r` to copy the folder into another machine,
this time, `du -m` get the overall disk usage: 12M,
very different.

Why does this happen?

I'm afraid some of the files or sub-folders are not copied fully,
so are there any other ways to check the total number of bytes?

Comment: Were there errors during the copy? Are all the files present in the copy? Do they have the same size? What was the exact `scp` command line: were you just copying the directory?

Comment: there is no errors. I think all files are present in the copy. They don't have the same size, but they have the same content. I used `scp -r`

Comment: Do you really have all the files (compare the output of `find | sort`)? If not, what can you spot about the ones that are missing? If you do, do all the files have the same size (compare the output of `du -ak | sort -k2`)?

Comment: I used `du -k|wc -l`, the number of files/subfolders is the same. But for the same file, the size is different, e.g, for a file on one machine it is 4K with `du -k` but 16 bytes with `du -b`, on another machine it is 0K with `du -k` and 16 bytes with `du -b`

Comment: What are the operating systems (Linux/OSX/Solaris/FreeBSD/Windows/…) and filesystems (ext4/btrfs/hpfs+/ffs/ntfs/…) on both sides? Are these a few big files or are there a lot of small files — how many files are there in total?

Comment: they are all linux. The big-sized folder is in a `ufs` system while the small-sized folder is in a `nfs` system. There are a lot of small files and many sub-folders within sub-folders. 1 to 2 thousand  files.

Answer (score 3):

Several possibilities.

a) scp may not have copied hidden files/directories; hard to tell w/o
knowing your data, seeing how you invoked scp.

b) another scenario will be that the filesystems use different block-sizes, and **du** doesn't add up the files byte sizes, it measures occupied disk space.

Comment: so how to get the file byte sizes?

Comment: and how to use `scp` so that even hidden files can be copied, but anyway, I don't think there are hidden files because the folder is full of data files which are produced by some of my programs

Comment: Have you considered using rsync?  As for the **how** .. show us how you did it, and describe the directory layout.

Comment: @misteryes `scp` doesn't care about dot files ("hidden files") so don't worry. Just the shell does when you invoke `scp`: `scp -r *.foo ...`

Comment: what is `Just the shell does when you invoke scp: scp -r *.foo ...`?

Comment: @misteryes You should use the @user comment feature so that those you address get informed. The shell expands `*.foo` to a list of files. `scp` doesn't see the `*`. In the default configuration the shell would remove a file name like `.file.foo` from this list because of the leading ".". You can check that with `echo *.foo; echo .*.foo`.

Comment: @misteryes, use `du -b` to get the apparent size rather than the actual used space.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, which is remote in my judgement: your original directory and the directories residing inside it have had a lot of files added and deleted. In most filesystems, directories only grow in size, never shrink.  The missing space could constitute unused slots in directories.

Comment: are there any other ways to check the total number of bytes?

Comment: But you can see the directory size, too: `ls -ld dir`

Comment: no, it is not correct, it shows 47 in the second field on both machines, but `du -m --summarize` show 12 on one machine and 89 on another machine